# Search and Replace cache duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, list, replace

I'm looking to do a simple search and replace of a list, however I've been trying to figure out how to cache after replacing so that I can use the same values later on.

For example -

```
lst = ["Mark","James","Steve","Mark","Steve"]
```

I need it to output -

```
newLst = ["User1","User2","User3","User1","User3"]
```

Cache each username so that if it is present more than once it can use the same amended name.

I've been attempting by storing in a dict.. but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try `collections.defaultdict`:

```py
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

lst = ["Mark", "James", "Steve", "Mark", "Steve"]

d = defaultdict(lambda c=count(1): next(c))

out = [f"User{d[name]}" for name in lst]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User1', 'User3']
```

Comment: What  if I wanted to be even more difficult and do this for a dictionary? 

For example - 


`dict = {"Mark":"User","James":"User","192.168.0.1":"Address","Mark":"User","192.168.0.1":"Adress","Process":"Chrome","Address":"192.168.0.1"}`

Getting this to return - 

`{"Mark":"User1","James":"User2","192.168.0.1":"Address1","Mark":"User1","192.168.0.1":"Adress1","Chrome":"Process1","192.168.0.1":"Address1"}`

Would this be easily possible? @AndrejKesely

Comment: @md1305 You cannot have duplicate keys in dictionary.

Comment: Duhh.. let me try again..

For example, I have the following -

`names = "Mark","Steve","Mark","Chrome","192.168.0.1","Mark","Chrome","192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2"]`

`type = ["user","user","user","process","address","user","process","adress","address"]`

And I'm hoping to get the following output -

`{
"Mark":"user1",
"Steve":"user2",
"Chrome":"process1",
"192.168.0.1":"adress1",
"192.168.0.2":"adress2"
}`

So trying to use the type in the the 2nd list to determine the item in the first list's corresponding value. @AndrejKesely

Comment: apologies about couple of typo's in there